# Html OnLoad Waiting

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<?php

//stuff


?>


<html>
<head>...header stuff...</head>
<body onLoad="start_my_script ();">
 .
 .
 .  //get values from php.
 .
 .

</body>
</html>
```

My php is getting a little like 3 to 4 secs. to load stuff.
So, its not getting passed in html.

is there any way I can put wait in onload till my php gets loaded.

Answer (score 2):

PHP runs when you request the page, not when the page is in the browser. Thus, PHP will process everything, make the final page, and send it to the browser. There is no chance for the browser to wait for the page to load before calling PHP.

Comment: To add to this, if you are expecting PHP values to be present in their script, they will not be.

One potential work-around would be to do something like

`<script>
var javascriptVariable = <?php echo $PHPVariable; ?>;`

Answer (score 0):

i'd load it asynchronous (jQuery) to address those issues. However, it would help if you specify what are you doing in your php script and how those results are used in the html document.